Proving that $f$ is topologically conjugate to its derivative map $x\to\lambda x$

Let $p$ be a hyperbolic fixed point for $f$ with $f'(p)=\lambda$ and
$\lambda\ne0$. Prove that $f$ is locally topologically conjugate to
its derivative map $x\to\lambda x$ as described in Sternberg's theorem.

Sternberg's theorem:
Let $p$ be a hyperbolic fixed point for $f$ and suppose $f'(p)=\lambda$ with $|\lambda|\ne[0,1]$. Then there are neighbourhoods $U$ of $p$ and $V$ of $0\in \mathbb{R}$ and a homeomorphism $h:U\to \mathbb{R}$ which conjugates $f$ on $U$ to the linear map $L(x)=\lambda x$ on V.
An attempt
Let $p$ be a hyperbolic fixed point for $f$ with $f'(p)=\lambda$ and $\lambda\ne0$, and there exists a conjugacy such that $f'(x)\circ h(x)=h(x)\circ f(x)$, where there exists a fixed point at $h(p)$ by the Sternberg theorem.
Consider $|x|$ in the fundamental domain $J=[-5,-1]\cup [1,5]$, and construct a conjugacy $h$ which is increasing such that $h(\pm5)=\pm5$. We define $h:[1,5]\to [f(5),5]$ and $h:[-5,-1]\to [-5, f(-5)]$, hence $h$ is linear.  Let $x\ne0$, then there exists $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f^n(x)$ belongs to the fundamental domain $J$. So, $h\circ f^n(x)$ is well-defined, and therefore $h$ must also be well-defined, since we have
\begin{equation}\begin{split}
      &h(x)=f'^{-n}\circ h\circ f^n(x)\\
      &g^n\circ h(x)=h\circ f^n(x)
      \end{split}
  \end{equation}
Now we define by Sternberg's theorem that there exists a fixed point which $f(p)=h(0)=\lambda\in J$and use the definition of a hyperbolic fixed point,
\begin{definition}
A hyperbolic equilibrium point $p$ is a fixed point, or equilibrium point, of $f$, such that $(Df)_p$ has no eigenvalue with absolute value $1$. In this case, $\lambda = p$. \end{definition}
Since the $|\lambda|\ne1$ for a hyperbolic fixed point, and $|\lambda|=[0,1]$, then $f$ can be topologically conjugate to $f'$ if and only if we have:
\begin{equation}
   \begin{split}
       &f'(h(p))=h'(f(p))\cdot f'(p)\cdot \frac{1}{h'(h(p))}\\
       &f'(h(p))=h'(p)\cdot \lambda \frac{1}{h'(p)}  \\
       &=\lambda=h(0)=p
   \end{split}
      \end{equation}
which applies to any linear conjugacy, $h$ i.e. $h(x)=\alpha x+\beta$, such that the hyperbolic point $p\in [0,1]$. Here the derivative map preserves the hyperbolicity of $p$ since the conjugacy $h$ is linear.
Any comments appreciated.
Thanks

What is the statement of Sternberg's Theorem? Also, are you asking to prove a case of Sternberg's Theorem (as the statement of the problem seems to imply)? Or are you instead supposed to apply Stenberg's Theorem (as your proof is worded)?

Well, the paragraph following the words An Attempt still seem to be worded as an application of Sternberg's Theorem, in which case your proof is circular because you are using what you have to prove.

@LeeMosher Hi Lee, I made an update. Do you have some comments? Thanks
